# Does editing my app description reset my app's ratings?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

When I make a minor edit to my app description in iTunesConnect, will it affect my app ratings or rankings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will not. Only releasing a new version will void ratings for the 'current version' (but still aggregate them in 'all versions'), as shown in the App Store.